# Proving that we have $A \subset K$ where $K$ is self-similar

Tags: real-analysis, fractals

Let $f_1, \ldots$, $f_N:X\to X$ be contractions in the complete metric space $X$, and $K$ the self-similar set with respect to the $f_i$. If $A\subset X$ is compact and

$$A\subset f_1(A)\cup\cdots\cup f_N(A)$$

what I am trying to prove is that then $A\subset K$.

So I was doing is the following, I was trying to prove that

$$ f_1(A)\cup\cdots\cup f_N(A) \subset  f_1(K)\cup\cdots\cup f_N(K)=K$$

so we pick a $x \in f_1(A)\cup\cdots\cup f_N(A)$ that means that we can write $x=f_i(a)$ for some $i$ and $a \in A$, but I don't know how to continue because I actually don't have anything that relates $A$ and $K$, another thing I was trying to do is to define $D=f_1(A)\cup\cdots\cup f_N(A) $ and $K=f_1(K)\cup\cdots\cup f_N(K)$, so $D,K$ are compact, and then use a result of compact spaces, but I really don't know which one could help me, because I don't know anyone that involves subsets of images of continous functions.

So, Can someone help me to prove the above theorem?

And other thing, Under the same hypothesis of the previous problem, if $B\subset X$ is nonempty and

$B\supset f_1(B)\cup\ldots\cup f_N(B)$,

then how do you prove that $\bar B \supset K$.

so Does  @JonhMa's answer is the same in this case?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I vaguely remember that the set mapping $A\mapsto f_1(A) \cup \cdots \cup f_n(A)$ is a contraction on the space of compact set with Gromov Hausdorff distance. Can you use this fact?

Comment: Yes, which definition of distance do you have?

Comment: That's in the book "Analysis on fractals" by Kigami p.10 (It's called a Hausdorff metric there).

Comment: the distance definition or the proof?

Comment: Is the one that talks about the infimum of the epsilons of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood right?

Answer (score 2):

One might assume that $A$ is nonempty, or the claim is trivial. I am following the notations in Kigami's book. Recall that one can define a metric $\delta$ on $\mathcal C(X)$, the space of nonempty compact subset of $X$, given by

$$\delta(A, B) = \inf\{ r > 0: A \subset U_r(B),\ \ B\subset U_r(A)\}.$$

This is a metric and the mapping $F : \mathcal C(X) \to \mathcal C(X)$ defined by 
$$F(A) = f_1(A) \cup \cdots f_n(A)$$

turns out to be a contraction in $(\mathcal C(X), \delta)$. Now let $A\in \mathcal C(X)$ such that $A \subset F(A)$. Then we have

$$A \subset F(A) \subset F^2(A) \subset \cdots \subset F^n(A) \cdots $$

and note that this sequence in $\mathcal C(X)$ converges to $K$ as $n\to \infty$, as $F$ is a contraction. Thus for all $r>0$, there is $N$ so that $\delta (F^N(A), K)<r$. Thus 
$$A \subset F^N(A) \subset U_rK.$$
As $r$ is arbitrary, 
$$A \subset \bigcap_{r>0} U_r(K)\Rightarrow A\subset \overline K = K. $$

**Remark** If we have instead $F(A) \subset A$, then we can conclude $K \subset A$. To see this, note that we have

$$\cdots F^n(A) \subset F^{n-1}(A) \subset \cdots \subset F(A) \subset A$$

for all $n$. Note again that $F_n(A) \to K$ in $\delta$. Thus for all $r>0$ there is $N$ so that $\delta (F^N(A), K) < r$. This implies

$$K \subset U_r F^N(A) \subset U_r(A)$$

Then the same argument implies that $K \subset \overline A = A$.

**Further remark** The above two results does not hold if $A$ is not compact. For example, let $X = [0,1]$ and $f_1 (x) = \frac x3$, $f_2(x) = \frac x3 + \frac 23$. Then the fixed point of $F$ is the Cantor set $\mathcal C$. If $A = (0,1)$, then $F(A) \subset A$, but $\mathcal C$ is not a subset of $A$ as $\{0,1\} \in \mathcal C$.

Comment: Let me check it out with detail, Can I let you know tomorrow if I have questions?

Comment: Only one thing, Are the $F^i$ compositions?

Comment: @user162343 You are welcome. (And yes, it's compositions)

Comment: Ok, so I'll comment here tomorrow :)

Comment: I am back :), my question is How can you conclude the las containtion? Thnks

Comment: And another question, what if the contention is the other way around, this is $F(A) \subset A$, does the  proof is the same?

Comment: for all $x\in A$, pick $r = 1/n$. Then there is $k_n \in K$ so that $d(x, k_n) <\frac 1n$. So $k_n \to x$ and $x\in \overline K$. If $F(A) \subset A$, the conclusion is $K \subset A$. The proof is more or less the same. @user162343

Comment: How do yuo adapt it ? Thanks

Comment: Well is because I think is a little bit difficult to deal with $F(A) \subset A$ and then $F(A) \subset F(A)^2$... Thanks :)

Comment: @user162343 Please see the edit.

Comment: You saw the the edit of my question right ? Thanks :)

Comment: Oops actually I didn't. I agree with what you said in your question that it is hard to relate directly $A$ and $K$. So to prove the theorem directly seems impossible. Also in the latter case I still need to assume $A$ is compact. @user162343

Comment: Right that is what I actually wrote, that down the same hypotheses , :), so what can be done in this case ? Thanks

Comment: @user162343 : This is also written in the remark in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so the second part is done with your remark right ? Or what is the difficult part to conclude ?

Comment: I mean it will be difficult if you do not use the fixed point theorem. If you use that, the theorem is not that hard to conclude. @user162343

Comment: And Can you explain me why the containtions changed ? Thanks  :)

Comment: I am just using that if $C\subset D$ then $F(C) \subset F(D)$. @user162343

Comment: Right, but you where using that fact in the other case right?

Comment: Then $F(A) \subset A \Rightarrow F^2(A) \subset F(A) \Rightarrow F^3(A) \subset F^2(A)\cdots $. @user162343

Comment: And as we can note, since $A$ (or $B$ in the case of my post) is Compact the it is closed so $\overline{A} =A$ right?

Comment: @user162343 : Yes. Indeed I think the statement is not true if $A$ is not closed.

Comment: Ok so let me check your remark in more detail, if I have further questions Can I let you know?

Comment: Sure! Just leave a comment ^^. @user162343

Comment: What If B is not comapct? Thanks

Comment: And we are talking about the closure of B :)

Comment: It seems that's depend on whether $\overline B$ is compact. @user162343

Comment: How is that?, well I think that it shouldn't since the hypothteses are only those I wrote :(, let me edit my post to clarify :)